# Plot a stacked barplot - amended

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph

I have 4 dataframes, which all have a column called Results showing Wins, Draws, Losses. I would like to create a layered histogram as the picture below. Any idea if it is achievable in R?

[image]

This is what I was playing with:

```
ggplot(results, aes(x = Country, y = ??)) + 


 geom_bar(aes(fill = Performance), stat = "identity")
```

Problem with this is I don't know what should I set the y axis to be. These are supposed to be counts

Another option I tried which is almost what I want is this:

```
counts <- table(results$Performance, results$Country)
barplot(counts, main="Game Count per Football Team",
        xlab="Football Teams", ylab = "Game Count", col=c("darkblue","red", "Yellow"),
        legend = rownames(counts))
```

Although the y axis stop at 800 although I have 908 observations max in one of the countries

Comment: You need the function `barplot`. There are examples in [QuickR](https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html)

Comment: how do you pass the 4 dataframes to create a Stacked Bar Plot? These dataframes all have a column called Results which can have values Wins, Draws, Losses. Sorry but I am completely new to R

Comment: Please read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Even if you are new to R and your attempt doesn't actually work, people are more likely to help if you show what you've tried.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you had all of this in just one dataframe rather than four dataframes. Do you absolutely have to have this broken out into four different dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can give you some code that will show you how you could do this. You basically would just want four different `geom_bar` statements.

To demonstrate, I'll create two different dataframes from the `mpg` dataset that comes with the `ggplot2` package, because you didn't provide any data.

```
library(tidyverse)

# I'm making two different data frames from the
# 'mpg' dataset, which comes with the ggplot package
mpg$year = as.character(mpg$year)
df1 = filter(mpg, year == "1999")
df2 = filter(mpg, year == "2008")

plot = ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=df1
           , aes(x = year, y = hwy, fill = manufacturer)
           , stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data=df2
           , aes(x = year, y = hwy, fill = manufacturer)
           , stat = "identity")

print(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need 2 data frames and 2 `geom_bar` calls, just work with long data. Use `mpg %>% filter(year %in% c(1999, 2008))` to have a long df that has those two years of data

Comment: I completely agree with you, but OP said they have four different data frames so I tried to accommodate for that. I left a comment on OP's post suggesting that they try to work with one dataframe rather than having four.